# my html selecting code select all the html boxs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made this jQuery code so i can click a link on top of an "htmlbox" to select what inside that "htmlbox"

```html
<p class="selecthtmlcode">إضغط هنا لتحديد النص أسفله</p>
<textarea readonly="" class="htmlcode">&lt;div id='allinantiadblock'&gt;
</textarea>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $( ".selecthtmlcode").click(function() { 
    $( ".htmlcode" ).select(); 
  }); 
});
```

but the problem is when i have more than one "htmlbox" (every one have a selecting link on top of it), it select only the last "htmlbox"

simply i want every link to select his "htmlbox" not the last one or all of them

here is my link that i have problem with 
http://showtime-info.blogspot.com/2014/04/24-anti-adblock.html

*by the way "إضغط هنا لتحديد النص أسفله" means "click here to select the Below text"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select the *next* `.htmlcode` element:

```
$(".selecthtmlcode").click(function() { 
  $(this).next(".htmlcode").select(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $(".selecthtmlcode").click(function() {
      $(this).next(".htmlcode").select(); 
   }); 
});
```

or possibly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $(".selecthtmlcode").click(function() {
      $(this).next(".htmlcode").val(); 
   }); 
});
```

Comment: no problem, i always appreciate up votes on comments and answer ;)

Comment: i want but when i try it said "vote up requires 15 reputation" and i don't know what to do! i have only 13 reputation.